# How to select all YAML keys based on a subkey value using yq?

Tags: select, conditional-statements, yq

I have a YAML file like this:

```
$ yq '.' test.yaml
{
  "entries": {
    "entry1": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "entry2": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "entry3": {
      "dummy": "TEST"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to select all entries having **enabled** attribute set to **true**:

```
$ yq '.entries | select(.[].enabled==true)' test.yaml
                         ^  ^
                         |  |
                         |  --- with enabled attribute set to true
                         ------ all entries
```

I expect the output to be

```
{
  "entry1": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

yet I get

```
{
  "entry1": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "entry2": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "entry3": {
    "dummy": "TEST"
  }
}
```

What did I get wrong?

Comment: Can you post the output of `yq --version`?

Comment: $ yq --version
yq 2.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to convert the object into an array, apply the selection to the array elements and then convert it back into an object. The filter `with_entries` does these conversions under the hood. It is a shorthand for `to_entries | map(foo) | from_entries` (see [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Basicfilters)).

The call is slightly different depending on the yq implementation used: [yq - Python](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) or [yq - Go](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/). The bash script contains calls for both implementations.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

INPUT='
{
  "entries": {
    "entry1": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "entry2": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "entry3": {
      "dummy": "TEST"
    }
  }
}
'

echo "yq - Go implementation"       # https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/
yq -j e '.entries | with_entries(select(.value.enabled == true))' - <<< "$INPUT"

echo "yq - Python implementation"   # https://github.com/kislyuk/yq
yq '.entries | with_entries(select(.value.enabled == true))' <<< "$INPUT"
```

#### output

```yaml
{
  "entry1": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Not working. I could not post the output as the formatting of code block is not functional in this comment. But the output of the command is the same as in my question.

Comment: I added a bash script in my answer ... so it's easier for you to test out the solution

Comment: $ ./test.sh 
Error: unknown command ".entries | with_entries(select(.value.enabled == true))" for "yq"
Run 'yq --help' for usage.

Comment: It seems that you are using yq - Go implementation and not the yq - Python implementation my solution was written for. I updated my answer. It contains calls for both implementations now.